# Invalid Syntax (pyflakes E)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am studying from a book "A guide to Python GUI programming with MySQL'. I have written two blocks of code:

```
project_dbcinfig.py

from configparser import ConfigParser

def read_db_configuration(filename='configuration_project.ini'):
  
    '''Read the database configuration file and generate a dictionary object
    :param filename: configuration filename
    :param section: section of database configuration
    :return: a dictionary that contains database parameters'''
    
    #Create a parser and read configuration
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)
    
    #Read section, the default is mysql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        arr_item = parser.items(section)
        for item in arr_item:
            db[item[0]] = item[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('{0} not found in the file {1}'.format(section,filename))
        
    return db
```

This is followed by:

```
project_connection.py

from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from project_dbconfig import read_db_configuration

def connect():
    '''Connect to MySQL Server'''
    
    konfig_db = read_db_configuration()
    try:
        print('Connect to MySQL...')
        Conn = MySQLConnection(**konfig_db)
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connection successfully established.')
        else:
            print('Connection failed.')
        except Error as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            conn.close()
            print('Connection closed')
if__name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

The problem I am getting is that the 'except' in the second block gives an invalid syntax error.

Can anybody help to solve this problem please. I am using Spyder as an editor and up to date Python and MySQL.

I am still learning so I don't know what to try. I suspect that the problem is in the previous code which I have copied verbatim from the book.